# How to fill a string array with strings in a loop and displaying?

Tags: java, android

I want to fill my "String[] collect" array with the variables of "String row" in a for cycle, and I dont know how to do that properly! And when the Array is filled I want to display it like a String with a textview.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<double[]> lokal = readCsv(getApplicationContext());

    for (double[] sor : lokal) {

        for (int i = 0; i < sor.length; i++) {
            mean(sor);
            String row = Double.toString(mean(sor));
            String[] collect = new String[] { row };
        }
    }

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    textView.setText(collect);

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `String Array` each time through your `loop`. Use an `ArrayList` as they can have a dynamic size and try something like

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   List<double[]> lokal = readCsv(getApplicationContext());

   ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();  // initialize ArrayList here, may want to declare as class variable

   for (double[]sor : lokal) {
    for(int i=0; i<sor.length; i++) {
       mean(sor);
       String row = Double.toString(mean(sor));
       array.add(row);   // add your String to it here
```

[ArrayList Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

To put all of the `String`s together just iterate over them. Something like

```
String result = ""
for (int c=0; c<array.size(); c++)
{
    String curString = array.get(c);
    result.concat(curString);
}
textview.setText(result);
```

if that doesn't work you can use

```
result = result + curString;
```

as "+" is the concatenation operator for `String`s

Comment: I got it, this will collect the strings in one ArrayList. But after collecting, how to convert the ArrayList into one string for displaying them with a textView?

Comment: I have edited. I haven't tried it but something like that should work. You may need to add formatting to `concat()` depending on what you want

Comment: Its working with `result = result + curString + "\n";` but the problem is, I got the results (means of a row) in equal times with the number of all individual numbers in the file, not the number of rows. For example: If I have just one row of numbers (for example with 4 numbers), then I want to display just one result not 4 times the same result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Take out the first `for loop` from what I understand you have. Its going to iterate over it for `lokal.length`

Comment: When I take out the second for loop `for(int i=0; i<sor.length; i++)` its iterate and display the results row by row, and thats what I need. Big, big THX for helping me out!

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure which one you actually needed. Glad I could help